# Crosswalk enable GPU Raster

Tags: performance, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I am using crosswalk 14.42.334.0 on my mobile app project. Today I turn on "show FPS meter" on chrome browser and I found that the GPU raster is off (device).

What is GPU raster? Will it significantly improve the performance? How can I enable it?

Answer (score 2):

In computing, hardware acceleration is the use of computer hardware to perform some function faster than is possible in software running on the general-purpose CPU. Examples of hardware acceleration include blitting acceleration functionality in graphics processing units (GPUs) and instructions for complex operations in CPUs.

It should improve your performance.

Using GPU rasterization:

**Chrome on Android:**
Use a meta viewport tag containing width=device-width and minimum-scale=1.0
e.g. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0">`
Nexus devices (except Nexus10), all devices with Android >= 4.4 that support OpenGL ES >= 3.0, all devices with Android > 4.4

**Chrome on Desktop**
In development (as of August 2015)
We will eventually enable GPU rasterization on all platforms and devices where we use the GPU for compositing. You can track progress towards this goal here.
To use the experimental hardware rasterizer on all pages, regardless of device and content: `--force-gpu-rasterization` or `chrome://flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization`
GPU Rasterization Veto:

Note that GPU rasterization can get vetoed based on the content itself. For example, if page contains many SVGs with non-convex paths (common for SVG icons), GPU rasterization may get disabled for that page load.

Here are the options you could see when you view your FPS meter

- off (device) - not supported on the device
- off (content) - supported on the device but content is veto'd for gpu rasterization (To see the content reason, record a trace using chrome://tracing (using cc) and search for the instant event 'GPU Rasterization Veto'.  The veto reason will be listed within the Args)
- off (viewport) - viewport trigger not available

Sources:
https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/chromium-graphics/how-to-get-gpu-rasterization
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/271264-chrome-gpu-hardware-acceleration-turn-off.html

Comment: Any idea on how to fix 'off (viewport) - viewport trigger not available'?